# How to remove all hidden parameters from Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, parameter

How do I remove all hidden parameters from Oracle Database before upgrading? I'm using the SQL query below. So what do you recommended?

```
SELECT name,description from SYS.V$PARAMETER WHERE name LIKE '\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Here are parameters:

```
_fast_full_scan_enabled
_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled
_like_with_bind_as_equality
_optimizer_push_pred_cost_based
_sort_elimination_cost_ratio
_sqlexec_progression_cost
_trace_files_public
_b_tree_bitmap_plans
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pfile from the spfile:

```
CREATE PFILE FROM SPFILE;
```

Edit the generated pfile and remove the parameters, then recreate the spfile from the edited pfile. Bounce the database & all should be well.

The database might need to be down when you recreate the spfile from the pfile.

Answer (score 7):

You'd need to add `IS_SPECIFIED` (or `ISSPECIFIED`) to the `where` clause, as some hidden parameters may be set by... other things.

A parameter can be removed from an spfile by issuing:

`ALTER SYSTEM RESET "_some_hidden_parameter" scope = spfile;`

You will likely have to stop and start the instance(s) to have the changes take effect.

Comment: Upvote for you. Didn't know about the `RESET` clause!

Comment: Oracle has a published document:   Doc ID 2518020.1
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=313588790448030&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=HOWTO&id=2518020.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=o2ur4zztl_4

Answer (score 0):

Please note when RAC you need to define scope=both

IE:

**Check if there are any hidden "_" parameters.**

```
SELECT name,description
FROM SYS.V$PARAMETER
WHERE name LIKE '\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

**Remove the hidden parameter, In my case it is "_rac_dbtype_reset"**

```
alter system reset "_rac_dbtype_reset" scope=both;
```

**Check again**

```
SELECT name,description
FROM SYS.V$PARAMETER
WHERE name LIKE '\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

**Then STOP and START the DB on ALL NODE in the RAC**

```
shutdown immediate;

startup;
```